# Load AutoCad DWG files in Python

Tags: python, autocad, arcpy, autocad-plugin

There a requirement to rendering AutoCad DWG file in Python.
My first Question is,

1:- Is is possible to render/load dwg file in python and view the file/image in python environment?

2:- How can I do that? I tried using arcpy, but as it is a proprietary software of ArcGIS, it is not possible to directly import the library? What are the alternatives to that?

I even explored a lot of sources on the internet but not found anything useful.
Tried comtypes.client also for importing and viewing the same.

```
import array
import comtypes.client
acad = comtypes.client.GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application")
doc = acad.ActiveDocument
ms = doc.ModelSpace
doc.Import("sample.dwg", array.array('d', [0, 0, 0]), 1.0)
```

I am getting this error, I have downloaded AutoCAD software also still I am getting this error. Please suggest what I am missing and what is the error actually means.

---

> OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> 3 try:
> ----> 4         acad = comtypes.client.GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application")
> 5 except:
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client_*init*_.py in GetActiveObject(progid, interface, dynamic)
> 172     """
> --> 173     clsid = comtypes.GUID.from_progid(progid)
> 174     if dynamic:
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\comtypes\GUID.py in from_progid(cls, progid)
> 77             inst = cls()
> ---> 78             _CLSIDFromProgID(str(progid), byref(inst))
> 79             return inst
> _ctypes/callproc.c in GetResult()
> OSError: [WinError -2147221005] Invalid class string

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
import comtypes.client
import time
try:
        acad = comtypes.client.GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application")
except:
        acad = comtypes.client.CreateObject("AutoCAD.Application")
while not acad.GetAcadState().IsQuiescent :
    time.sleep(5)
acad.Visible = True
doc = acad.Documents.Open("C:\\Temp\\Sample.dwg")
```

Comment: Hi @gileCAD, I am getting this error,

OSError
      3 try:
-> 4         acad = comtypes.client.GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application")
      5 except:
\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py in GetActiveObject(progid, interface, dynamic)
--> 173     clsid = comtypes.GUID.from_progid(progid)

\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\comtypes\GUID.py in from_progid(cls, progid)
     77             inst = cls()
-> 78             _CLSIDFromProgID(str(progid), byref(inst))
_ctypes/callproc.c in GetResult()

OSError: [WinError -2147221005] Invalid class string

Comment: GetActiveObject succeeds when AutoCAD is already running. If it fails CreateObject should start a new AutoCAD process. In both cases, AutoCAD have to be installed on the computer.

Comment: AutoCAD is installed and opened still this error is coming, unable to move further from this error. Do AutoCAD required env. setup in windows 10 or python require any path importing stuff like that before running this.